# admin but not storage pointing to the right project

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

In my project I have setup a dev and production environment by doing this:

```
const firebaseConfig =
  process.env.FUNCTIONS_EMULATOR === "true"
    ? {
        apiKey: process.env.FIREBASE_DEV_KEY,
        authDomain: "myapp-dev.firebaseapp.com",
        projectId: "myapp-dev",
        storageBucket: "myapp-dev.appspot.com",
        messagingSenderId: "...",
        appId: "...",
        measurementId: "...",
      }
    : {
        apiKey: process.env.FIREBASE_PROD_KEY,
        authDomain: "myapp-production.firebaseapp.com",
        projectId: "myapp-production",
        storageBucket: "myapp-production.appspot.com",
        messagingSenderId: "...",
        appId: "...",
        measurementId: "...",
      }

admin.initializeApp(firebaseConfig)
```

Then firestore points to the right project because it was initialized from `admin` like above:

```
const firestore = admin.firestore()
```

However, I am now trying to listen to storage uploads.
And by default, it is listening to my production app. I need to listen to uploads to my dev project.

The problem arises since the storage listener is coming from `functions` and not `admin` (which was initialized with the right config).

How can I "initialize" the storage listener (below) so that it listens to the dev project?

```
exports.generateThumbnail = functions.storage
  .object()
  .onFinalize(async (object) => {})
```

Is there maybe a way to attach a listener to `admin.storage()`?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but it seems like you are using the [Client SDK configuration](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/7015592) in the Cloud function. The [Admin SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup) uses a [service account](https://firebase.google.com/support/guides/service-accounts) instead of the client config.

> The FIREBASE_CONFIG environment variable is included automatically in Cloud Functions for Firebase functions that were deployed via the Firebase CLI.

That being said, you just need to initialize the Admin SDK as shown below:

```
import * as admin from 'firebase-admin';

admin.initializeApp()
```

Talking about the environments, I can clearly see that you have two different projects for different environments. In that case you would have to deploy the functions to both the project separately because the Admin SDK which uses service account for the dev project will be listening for changes in the dev project only

Other option would be initializing the Admin SDK twice as mentioned in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup#initialize-multiple-apps).

You can also consider using the same Firebase project for both dev and production but use different buckets for them. That way you can listen to those buckets separately. For [listening to a specific bucket](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/gcp-storage-events#trigger-function-on-storage-changes), specify it's name:

```
const devFunction = functions.storage.bucket('dev-bucket').object().onFinalize(async (object) => {
  //...
})

const prodFunction = functions.storage.bucket('prod-bucket').object().onFinalize(async (object) => {
  //...
})
```